# How to determine IP address of guest operating system in qemu?

Tags: networking, virtualization, dhcp, kvm-virtualization, qemu

After I boot a Windows XP in qemu it gets an IP assigned from DHCP server. My question is - how do I determine the IP that Windows XP got assigned, so that I can connect to Windows XP?

Here are more details about my setup:

I run `dnsmasq` on tun0 interface. I've set it up to give IPs from range 10.10.10.0/24. I use `-net tun` for qemu. I run multiple Windows XP guest installations so I can't use static IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a static IP in Windows XP and you can use that to connect to your VM.

Another alternative is that you can tell Dnsmasq to allocate a static IP address to the VM's MAC address.

Dnsmasq stores its DHCP leases into file specified with the `-l` or `--dhcp-leasefile` option. One can parse that file for IP address information.

Comment: Downvoted because your answer is completely off. I didn't ask anything about static addresses. You could as well have said "Buy a new computer with Windows XP and don't use qemu."

Comment: @BodaCydo: While the "assign static IP in XP" part indeed doesn't answer your question, you missed the excellent suggestion of configuring your DHCP server to assign fixed IPs to specific MAC addresses. This is usually much easier and more reliable than parsing the leases files.

Answer (score 1):

Check your DHCP server's leases file. I'm not sure what you're using for that, but `dhcpd` or `isc-dhcp-server` on Linux store their leases file in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`. `dnsmasq` stores its leases file in `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`. Either will have the IP address assigned, the time it was assigned, the MAC address it was assigned to, and the hostname the client responded with during negotiation.

Alternatively, you can use SDN tools like OpenDaylight to get active inventory of your environment as it's deployed. For smaller deployments, just using the DHCP leases file works fine.

Alternative to even that, you could just open a VNC console to the guest and use `ipconfig` within Windows XP to get an address of a particular guest. That gets tedious very quickly, and some kind of software reporting becomes necessary after having to administrate more than ten or so boxen.